# Error in self-invoking function inside render when updating React state

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-maps

I am writing a React Native application using [react-native-maps](https://github.com/react-community/react-native-maps). On my map, I am dynamically populating a number of [circles](https://github.com/react-community/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/circle.md) by using the [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method inside a self-invoking function. See the following code located in the component's render function:

```
{
  (() => {
    return this.state.mapviewPolygon.map(circle => (
      <MapView.Circle
        center={circle.coordinates}
        key={circle.key}
      />
    ))
  })()
}
```

This works fine on initial rendering. I later update `this.state.mapviewPolygon` based on where the user clicks on the map, with the intention that the circles will re-render based on the new set of coordinates.

However, when this self-invoking function fires, I receive the error `TypeError: undefined is not a function (near '..._this2.state.mapviewPolygon.map...')`, which doesn't tell me much. Likewise, the stack trace is of negligible help.

What is happening? How do I get the circles to properly re-render?

EDIT 1: See my entire render function below:

```
render() {

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>

        <MapView
          style={styles.map}
          showUserLocation
          followUserLocation
          loadingEnabled
          region={this.getMapRegion()}
          scrollEnabled = {this.state.mapviewScroll}
          onPress= { (e) => {
                let stateCopy = Object.assign({}, this.state.mapviewPolygon);
                // circleKey is a variable containing the index of 
                // the item in the state array to change
                stateCopy[circleKey].coordinates = e.nativeEvent.coordinate;
                this.setState({mapviewPolygon: stateCopy});
              }
            }
        >

         {
            this.state.mapviewPolygon.map(circle => 
                  <MapView.Circle
                    center={circle.coordinates}
                    key={circle.key}
                    radius={50}
                    fillColor={'#4286f4'}
                  />
                )
          }

          <MapView.Polygon
            coordinates={this.getPolygonCoords()}
            fillColor="rgba(0, 200, 0, 0.5)"
            strokeColor="rgba(0,0,0,0.5)"
            strokeWidth={2}
          />
        </MapView>

      </View>
    );
  }
```

Comment: Just try using `{ this.state.mapviewPolygon.map(circle => <MapView .../> ) }` in your render function.

Comment: Same thing happens.

Comment: Could you post your entire `render` function?

Comment: Done. (Please note that I went ahead and implemented your suggestion in the earlier comment as it is more concise and leads to the same performance I've had so far.)

Comment: Also, if it helpful: `stateCopy` is a copy of `this.state.mapviewPolygon` using `Object.assign` in which I change one of the values.

Comment: try to log and see the value of  `this.state.mapviewPolygon` in the render function.  **map** function is a property of an Array. If your `this.state.mapviewPolygon` is **undefined** or **null** then this Error will come. Just make sure that value is an Array

Comment: @cheekujha That pointed me in the right direction to find the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re changing mapviewPolygon from what is probably an array into an object when you do:

```
let stateCopy = Object.assign({}, this.state.mapviewPolygon);
```

map isn’t a method of object; hence the error. If you want to make a copy of an array, use something like:

```
let stateCopy = [...this.state.mapviewPolygon];
```

Or

```
let stateCopy = this.state.mapviewPolygon.slice();
```

Comment: I'll go ahead and give this to you since it's correct. I'll leave my own answer up as well for others' reference.

Answer (score 0):

The answer turned out to be that `stateCopy` is an incorrect type. Since `this.state.mapviewPolygon` is an array of objects, using `Object.assign` was an error. So I replaced this:

```
let stateCopy = Object.assign({}, this.state.mapviewPolygon);
```

With this:

```
let stateCopy = [];
  for (let i in this.state.mapviewPolygon) {
    stateCopy.push(this.state.mapviewPolygon[i]);
};
```

This works because `map` is now receiving an array instead of an object.